# Количество сравнений в сортировке

Tags: c++, сортировка, qsort

Считается ли за сравнения то что в цикле while, а если это был бы цикл for? Или циклы вообще не считаются за сравнения везде, а только If'ы. Не только в этой сортировке.

```
void quickSort(int *array, int first, int last)
{

    M = 0, C = 0;
    int left = first;
    int right = last;
    int midle = array[(left + right) / 2]; // minimalnaya trydoemkost' pri mid
    // poka levii - pervii element < pravogo - poslednego
    while (left <= right)
    {
        C++;
        // prosmatrivaya mas s leva naidem element < chem mid
        while (array[left] < midle)
            left++;
        C++;
        // prosmatrivaya mas s leva naidem element > chem mid
        while (array[right] > midle)
            right--;
        C++;
        // esli naidenii levii element menishe pravogo
        if (left <= right)
        {
            // menyaem ix mestami
            std::swap(array[left], array[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
            M += 3;
        }
        C++;
    }
    // elsi
    C++;
    if (right > first)
        quickSort(array, first, right);
    // esli
    C++;
    if (left < last)
        quickSort(array, left, last);
}
```

Comment: Сравнение, это применение любого оператора сравнения в коде.

Comment: Это зависит от убеждений вашего препода.